# What mainstream denominations (if any) hold a Young Earth Creationist view?

Tags: young-earth-creation

As the title asks, which mainstream denominations hold a YEC View?

Comment: I am not sure there are any but good question. For example I go to an Anglican church, believe YEC view, but as far as I know this is weakly discourage by various leaders in my denomination. So I suspect we are scattered everywhere without centralizing in any specific denomination. I could be wrong. Good question.

Comment: Do the standards of this board frown upon incomplete answers-- "I know of three: X, Y, Z"?

Comment: @pterandon I believe not, seeing as how the answers to this question could change over time some answers could be wrong as of tomorrow.

Comment: Many preachers believe in YEC but not all. Denominations are based upon doctrines mostly and views like YEC is a personal matter.

Comment: @pterandon Three is sufficient I think. Just give a good format of it.

Comment: @Mawia I would think YEC is a doctrine of the 7th day adventist church. EG White, their prophet, had a vision concerning the creation, seeing it occur in 6 literal days. That particular vision is marked as evidence for the keeping of the Sabbath.

Comment: This is essentially a "list question" (or a straw poll question), which are pretty much frowned upon on all S.E. sites.  http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/1532/how-should-we-handle-list-questions

Answer (score 5):

Typically, any congregation professing the YEC viewpoint are going to be non denominational. Though the name implies there is an unspecified disagreement among non denominational churches, the vast majority are biblical litetalists. This means they will naturally take the YEC view.

As Mawia pointed out in a comment, the date of the creation, and even the very process, is considered a matter of opinion in most denominations and not a doctrine.

Specifically, [7th Day Adventists are biblical literalists and therefore young earth creationists](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/16239/what-are-the-main-differences-between-7th-day-adventists-and-catholic-protestant/16250#16250). They are the only denomination that I know of that explicitly holds that view.

---

Considering their shared roots with 7th Day Adventism, some think that Jehovah's Witnesses are Young Earth Creationists. Instead, [it seems they are not](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/31320/what-do-jehovahs-witnesses-believe-about-evolution). They are Progressive Creationists, which is a variety of Old Earth Creationism that excludes Evolution.

Comment: @Bruce from most places I see, jw's take a kind of day age theory with some possible gap theory.